# UML и IntellijIdea

Tags: ide, java, intellij-idea

Подскажите, можно ли подключить UML к IntellijIdea? Если можно подключить, то как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file\settings -> закладка Plugins -> закладка Available -> в поиске набираете UML, и разбираетесь с любым плагином.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

В `IDEA` присутствует отличная нативная поддержка UML - http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/uml_class_diagram.html

Comment: Это только в платной версии.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m Справа же написано, что и в `Community` тоже. Или я не знаю чего-то?)

Comment: Даже и не знаю.. но в основной поставке я не вижу ничего такого в Community.. может надо что установить? В платной у меня эта штука просто работает и всё..

Answer (score 0):

Простая и бесплатная программа которая построит UML диаграммы классов из java проекта. Пока доступна Desktop версия, но скоро появятся плагины для IDEA и Eclipse.
http://www.java2uml.ru/index.html